# ATL CCommand Close on destruction

Tags: c++, sql, atl

I'm using ATL to communicate with a SQL database through OLEDB.

My question is whether or not I have to explicitly call `CCommand::Close` if I've previously called `Open` or whether the `CCommand` destructor will clean up.

I have a feeling that I must call `Close` but it would be nice if I didn't have to!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my comment to Daniel's answer. Destructor cleans it up and you don't have to worry. MSDN code snippet would have destructor called after `CoUninitialize` and this is the only reason they do explicit `ReleaseCommand` in order to release interfaces prior to shutting down COM.

They could have it done like this instead:

```
CoInitialize(...);
{
  CCustomer rs; 
  // ...
  // rs.ReleaseCommand() <<-- Not needed
  // rs.Close() <<-- Not needed
}
// NOTE: ~CCustomer already worked, it is safe to shut COM down
CoUninitialize();
```

Why? ATL's `atldbcli.h`:

```
~CAccessorRowset()
{
    Close();
}

// ...

~CCommandBase()
{
    ReleaseCommand();
}

// ...

class CCommand :
    public CAccessorRowset<TAccessor, TRowset>,
    public CCommandBase,
    public TMultiple
```

So `CCommand`'s destructor does it all.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Does the same apply to `Close`?

Comment: Yes, the same applies to `Close`. It is also auto-called by destructor. Updated answer above to indicate this in first place.

Comment: Can you provide a source for this? If so I'll accept your answer!

Comment: Ahhh, perfect. I should really have looked there myself!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to call both `Close` and `ReleaseCommand` as described in the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zax0c796.aspx).

Comment: Thanks @Daniel. I read that but just wondered whether the destructor of CCommand would do any clean-up especially in the situation where an exception is raised. The documentation doesn't say anything so I'm guessing not.

Comment: Yes, but note that `~ССommand` does `ReleaseCommand` behind the scenes. Destructor cleans it up, you only need explicit call if you are to sort of reuse the command instance. MSDN's example is not so good, they do it explicitly because they have to have it done by their `CoUninitialize`...